# android views inside a table layout?

Tags: android

I have 6 icons that I put in a TableLayout with 2 icons per row.

So this is how the layout looks like:

```
    <TableLayout
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:shrinkColumns="*">
      <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="2"/>
      <TableRow>
...
      </TableRow>
      <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
      <TableRow>
...
      </TableRow>
      <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
      <TableRow>
...
      </TableRow>
      <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="4"/>

    </TableLayout>
```

When the Views have equal weight, this layout looks fine. However, if I change their weights to what is shown, the layout doesn't come out quite right.

I have attached a screenshot to this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/76rXS.png[image]

Any suggestions on getting this to work?

Comment: I am more lost looking at the image, can you show what you want in another simpler image without random grey bits? Also as mohsin.mr has said I would use a relative or linear layout as the table layout is probably more work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use RelativeLayout rather than TableLayout on design mode of eclipse

Comment: I want to keep TableLayout because it allows me to align the buttons nicely in a grid manner.